# Recursive function data in array not comes as expected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

i want to display some result using recursion
first here is my table structure

```
contactid       name        reportsto
 244797          ankit         9876
 438             Mukti         244797
 445             Moorthy       244797
 446             P K Roy       244797
 448             Suruchi       438
 542             Lalit Kumar   438
 543             Balkrishan    542
```

this is my table contact where all contacts been stored
Now i want when contactid 244797 is login then all ids whose reports to 244797 is shown and also contact id who reported to any of id related to 244797 for example 448 and 542 shown because it reported to 438 and also 543 its reported to 542 if any if anyone reported different means not in contact id loop is terminate and all contacts stored in an array.
this is my php code

```
$contactid=$_SESSION['customer_id'];
$i=0;
function contactId($contactid='') {
  $sqlq="select contactid,firstname,lastname,reportsto from contactdetails where reportsto=".$contactid."";
  $res=mysql_query($sqlq);
  //$contacts=array();
  $links = array();
if($row = mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){

     while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     //echo "<pre>"; print_r($rows);
           $links[$i]['id'] = $rows['contactid'];
           $links[$i]['firstname'] = $rows['firstname'];
           $links[$i]['lastname'] = $rows['lastname'];
           $links[$i]['reportsto'] = $rows['reportsto'];
          contactId($rows['contactid']);
          $i++;
    }

}

 return $links;   

}


$printres=contactId($contactid);
```

when i print_r($printres) then i receive only id whose reported to 244797 please check my code and evaluate my problem thanks.
the output i receives looks like

```
 Array
(
[] => Array
    (
        [id] => 438
        [firstname] => Mukti
        [lastname] => Srivastava
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 445
        [firstname] => Moorthy
        [lastname] => NA
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 446
        [firstname] => P K Roy
        [lastname] => Choudhary
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )

  )
```

and output i want which is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 438
        [firstname] => Mukti
        [lastname] => Srivastava
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 445
        [firstname] => Moorthy
        [lastname] => NA
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 446
        [firstname] => P K Roy
        [lastname] => Choudhary
        [reportsto] => 244797
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 448
        [firstname] => suruchi
        [lastname] => Choudhary
        [reportsto] => 438
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 542
        [firstname] => lalit kumar
        [lastname] => Choudhary
        [reportsto] => 438
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 543
        [firstname] => balkrishan
        [lastname] => Choudhary
        [reportsto] => 542
    )

   )
```

Comment: Your statements are not clear. Can you explain a bit more. May be based on input what expected output you want, that will clear it more

Comment: What do you want your result array to look like? Show the desired output and the one you're getting here.

Comment: Dear @Anant based on table i want all ids which relate to 244797 and its reported by id and also ids of id reported by

Comment: I pretty much doubt the current output shown is real one. It'd be major bug to have array element w/o any key (be it generated or manually assigned) and this is what your output suggests.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sir from my code the output is like you see please correct my code if any error

Comment: what I am saying is that I never seen array elements w/o keys and this is what your `print_r()` suggests. Tried using `var_dump()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

Please, consider using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions instead of `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated because of security reasons.

```
<?php

function getReports($contactId, $pdo) 
{
    $reports = [];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        'SELECT contactid as id, firstname, lastname, reportsto '.
        'FROM contactdetails '.
        'WHERE reportsto = :contactId');
    $stmt->bindValue(':contactId', $contactId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $reports = array_merge($reports, [$row], getReports($row['id'], $pdo));
    }

    return $reports;
}

$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

$contactId = $_SESSION['customer_id']; 
$reports   = getReports($contactId, $pdo);
```

As asked by the question owner, the `mysql_*` version (assuming connexion is already open), but remember **it's not recommended** :

```
<?php

function getReports($contactId) 
{
    $reports = [];
    $res = mysql_query(
        'SELECT contactid as id, firstname, lastname, reportsto '.
        'FROM contactdetails '.
        'WHERE reportsto = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($contactId) . '"');

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $reports = array_merge($reports, [$row], getReports($row['id']));
        }
    } 

    return $reports;
}

$contactId = $_SESSION['customer_id']; 
$reports   = getReports($contactId);
```

Comment: if i use mysql then what should be your code look please reply

Comment: *"If i use mysql..."*: then you ***should*** move away from it now. It is not a difficult task.

Comment: $reports = array_merge($reports, [$row], getReports($row['id'])); what is [$row]

Comment: i does't find contacts with id that reports to 438